# Featherlight : instructions followed but not working

Tags: featherlight.js

Well, I followed all the instructions and it doesn't work at all.
Here is the page concerned by the problem : https://www.fluidtopics.com/take-a-tour/whats-new/
Featherlight is setup on the first big image (floating at right of the text) to open a lightbox with a video inside.
I don't know where's the problem but it seems that the plugin doesn't fire.

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine, except your whole site has a `z-index` of 250, so the featherlight box opens "behind".

Change `featherlight's` CSS to a `z-index` of 250 or higher and you will see the dialog box.

The default `z-index` [has been increased](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/commit/63fea044d6d02e85f316e94f37d1607088c48a27) to avoid this in future releases.

Comment: That was so simple... thanks a lot for your help !! Now the player doesn't work but that's another subject ;-)